# Pythonic way to specify object configurations

Tags: python, constructor

I have an object that takes 5 configuration parameters, like so;

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=4):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
```

However, I want to offer a few sets of default configurations rather than just one, e.g. also `(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)` and `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`, and preferably give them sane names. What would be the most Pythonic approach? Some of the options I've considered are a `@classmethod` that produces the instance, or an instance method that configures an instance.

Comment: how would the default configurations be selected/chosen?

Comment: That is inherent to the solution, it seems. Via a class method for each configuration, it would imply calling this class method (`A.configname()`). When using a parameter in `__init__` or a configuration method, well, something like `A('configname')`. That's the core of the question, really. Subclassing `A`.. well.. I wouldn't immediately see how that would work nicely while staying transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have a single class method that maps to a dictionary of preset configs:

```
class A(object):

    CONFIGS = {
        'default': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 4},
        ...
    }

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config='default'):
        if config not in cls.CONFIGS:
            raise ValueError('invalid config: {!r}'.format(config))
        return cls(**cls.CONFIGS[config])
```

This is then easily scalable to an arbitrary number of configurations, and instances can be created using:

```
a = A.from_config(config_name)
```

You could still provide default parameter values for `__init__`, but leaving them out means the user gets an error if they try to use `A()` rather than `A.from_config()`; whether that's a good thing is up to you, but I think there's a benefit to making the user consistently use either `from_config` or explicit custom parameters.

Subclasses can simply define their own `CONFIGS` dictionary and use the inherited `from_config` and potentially even `__init__`.

---

In terms of the other options:

- Separate class methods for each preset would play nicely with IDEs, but doesn't scale or inherit very well (for example, what do you do if a child doesn't support one of its parent's presets?);
- An `__init__` that took either the parameters or the config name would be overcomplicated and error prone; and
- An instance method to configure an instance might be useful if you need to *reconfigure* them, and could be implemented similarly to my class method (the interface could be e.g. `a = A().configure(config_name)`, where `configure` would `return self`), but the class method makes it clearer that the config should be set at creation time and not changed.

---

The functionality is simple enough that you could extract it into a mix-in class for reuse elsewhere:

```
class Configurable(object):
    """Mix-in for creating instances from preset configs."""

    CONFIGS = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        if config not in cls.CONFIGS:
            raise ValueError('invalid config: {!r}'.format(config))
        args, kwargs = cls.CONFIGS[config]
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)


class A(Configurable, ...):  # can still include any other inheritance

    CONFIGS = {
        'default': ((), {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 4}),
        ...
    }

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config='default'):
        return super(A, cls).from_config(config)
```

Note that, for widest possible reuse, I've now provided separately for positional `args` and named `kwargs`, and removed the default `config`.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an optional parameter to the constructor, it could be done as

```
class A(object):
    par_names = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    defaults = {'default': (1, 2, 3, 4, 4),
                'second':  (1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
                'third':   (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)}

    def __init__(self, cfg='default', *args, **kwargs):
        if cfg not in self.defaults:
            raise ValueError('invalid config: {!r}'.format(cfg))
        if len(args) > len(self.defaults[cfg]):
            raise TypeError('invalid number of arguments: max {!r}'.format(
                                                    len(self.defaults[cfg])))
        for n, v in zip(self.par_names, args):
            setattr(self, n, v)

        cfg_defs = dict(zip(self.par_names, self.defaults[cfg]))
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k not in cfg_defs:
                raise TypeError('{!r} is an invalid keyword argument for this configuration'.format(k)) 
            setattr(self, k, v)
        for k, v in cfg_defs.items():
            setattr(self, k, self.__dict__.get(k, v))
```

It allows you to instantiate the object normally, getting the defaults from the appropriate configuration when specified, otherwise get the default values form the default configuration (i.e. `default`).

Sample use:

```
>>> a=A()
>>> a.a
1
>>> a.b
2
>>> a.c
3
>>> b=A('third',a=8,c=6)
>>> b.a
8
>>> b.c
6
>>> c=A('third')
>>> c.a
5
```

as well as using positional and/or keyword arguments:

```
>>> a=A('second',8,9)
>>> a.a
8
>>> a.b
9
>>> a.c
1
>>> a.d
2
>>> b=A('second',8,9,c=10,d=11)
>>> b.a
8
>>> b.b
9
>>> b.c
10
>>> b.d
11
>>> b.e
1
```

Comment: This sort of proves my point! The result is *"some default plus arbitrary overrides"*, which seems unintuitive, and you lose the actual parameter definitions from `__init__`. Note that `v if k not in kwargs else kwargs[k]` can be rewritten `kwargs.get(k, v)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, of course. In fact your solution is the best one (upvoted). Thanks for the `kwargs.get` oops. I am working on it to make it accept positional args as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd also go with an optional config argument in the constructor. The most general solution (assuming None is not a valid configurator) is to obtain a list of explicit positional or named initializers and a list of config-specified initializers, merge them, and check that there are no `None` values. Something like:

```
DEFAULTS = { 'name': (1,2,3,4,5),
             'another': (2,3,4,5,6),
             'zero_de': (None,None,None,0,0),
             # etc
           }

def __init__( self, a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None,e=None, config=None):

   explicit = [ a,b,c,d,e ]

   if config is None:
      config = (None,None,None,None,None)
   else:
      if config in DEFAULTS:
         config = DEFAULTS[config]
      else
         raise ValueError, 'config name {} not valid'.format( config)

   values = [ ee if ee is not None else ii for ee,ii in zip( explicit, config) ]

   if any( [v is None for v in values ] ):
       raise ValueError, 'object not fully specified: {}'.format(values)

   self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d,self.e = values
```

Comment: are you sure `DEFAULTS` is reachable from within `__init__`?

Comment: and what if tomorrow the number of parameters increases? Way too many changes would be needed.

Comment: The question says "an object that takes five parameters", no mention of increasing. But if it should, almost no change is needed. Add `f=None` to the `__init__` signature, add `f` to the list `explicit`, add `self.f` to the final assignment, add another `None` in the conditional `config is None` code, update the `DEFAULTS` to match the new object structure. All both obvious and unavoidable.

Comment: However, you could do `__init__(self, *args, config=None)` should your objects require an arbitrary number of parameters to define them. Details of rest of code would change, broad-brush outline would not.

Comment: and what about the assignment of the attributes? (last line). BTW, please fix the error (see my first comment).

Comment: "Something like". It's not intended to be a complete piece of code, that's why there's no class definition. If you wrap it in a class definition (implied by the use of `self` and `__init__`, it is accessible as a class attribute, exactly as it is in your answer. I don't believe it needs fixing, especially not after adding this comment.

Comment: Last line is correct: a tuple assignment of form `a,b,c=values_list` . Some might prefer `(self.a,self.b,...)=tuple(values_list)` but it's not necessary.